# Ubuntu 16.04 black screen after logo with Nvidia proprietary

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, login-screen, nouveau, proprietary

Straight to the point. I have an Intel I5 + Nvidia GTX 560 with 8Gb Ram.
I installed Ubuntu 16.04.0 (without any updates) 3 days ago, and it was able to run and boot with nvidia drivers version 367 installed (nvidia-367). No problems at all.

Then, after a couple of updates yesterday, I cannot boot past the ubuntu logo anymore. The system only works with the nouveau driver, when I boot an older kernel without nvidia installed, which is not the optimal solution since nouveau's support for graphic intensive applications is horrendous.

I am stuck on a completely black screen with a white cursor sometimes blinking, sometimes not, at the top of it. Also, some horizontal artifacts quickly occur and go away during this same black screen.

I already tried to boot with 'nomodeset' 'nouveau.modeset=0' and every other imaginable option. I cannot even press 'Ctrl + Alt + F1' since that results in nothing, however I can reboot the PC pressing and holding 'Ctrl + Alt + Del'.

With the parameter 'nosplash' I could see that the screen asks for my login name and password. But when it reaches this point, I cannot do anything else, it becomes completely stuck and unresponsible the same moment the OS is 'ready' - not even the keyboard works (apart from, of course, the Ctrl Alt Del combination).

I rebooted so many times that I could get to the login GUI once, and after entering my password everything hung again. Including the mouse cursor.

Any ideas?

Comment: To close voters: the issue turned out to be entirely hardware-specific.

Answer (score 1):

Solved: Apparently my GTX 560 was kind of loose in its PCI-e slot after I'd opened the case to add a couple of new fans. Thus, when put under minimal stress - like showing the OS GUI - it was shutting the screen off (windows) or showing up a blank screen (ubuntu). I removed the card completely, reinserted it, reinstaled the latest drivers and everything is fine again.

Cheers to everyone who tried to help!